# How can I bend artwork by 25°?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, illustration, print-production, packaging

I am doing a packaging for a client and when I received the shape of the container I found out that it should be bent by 25° and I want to know how to do that please.

One solution is to bend the final image in Photoshop, but I believe there is a way working with perspectives.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "bend"? Your comment on @Lucian's answer makes it sound like that answer is not what you're looking for. But if it's not, then I have no idea what you *are* looking for. Maybe you could give an example of an image and what it would look like after being "bent"?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Use the 'Warp' feature in Illustrator (for vector artwork)

- create your artwork inside a straight rectangle
- group and select the artwork
- with this selected, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> which opens up the 'Warp Options' dialog (or via the menu 'Object → Envelope Distort → Make with Warp')
- select the 'Arc' style and type '13.889%' in the 'Bend' field (25° is 13.889 percent of 180°)

[image]

### Use the 'Warp' feature in Photoshop (for non-vector artwork)

- group all your layers into a single Group, or merge all layers
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> the resulting group or layer, right click and choose 'Warp'
- choose 'Arc' and type '13.889%' in the 'Bend' field (which should be located right under your main menu)

Comment: its great i didn't even think about it because u can't bend images :/ if there is a way to do it it would be the best thing ever if not i'll find a way :D thank you very much

Comment: Where did you come up with this number: 13.889%?

Comment: It's a secret I guess

Comment: @BANG  I gave it. You can find the proof by following the edit chain backwards. Lucian removed the credit after my account was closed. and my reputation was zeroed by the high rank members. due arguing against one of them. Fortunately the ban did not be final. The number is "how many percentages the wanted angle is of 180 degrees".

Comment: @user287001 Thanks for the reply... Didn't even know there was drama. I only wanted to know how the calculation had been made. That said, giving credit where credit is due has always been a thing for me. Seems a little odd that such credit should have been removed... Anyhow, for anyone else reading, to be clear, user287001 is saying that 25° is 13.889 percent of 180°. I shall attempt to edit and improve the answer to state this plainly and leave no mystery.