# How to create closed arc shape with slanting sides in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shapes

I.e. an open fan shape:

[image]

Thank you so much!

Comment: Similar question: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/91364/62949

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the pen tool.

1. Use guides to map out your dimensions.

[image]

2. Select the pen tool and start off with creating the top and bottom arcs.

[image]

3. Connect and adjust the sides.

[image]

4. Go to the paths panel (Window>Paths) and save the path

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. Draw out a rectangle
2. Once you have the rectangle drawn, choose Edit > Trasnform > Warp
3. Then change the type of warp you'd like to do using the drop down in the Options Bar. Choose Arc

[image: Arc]

4. You can then enter a value for the amount of arc, or you can use the transform handles to manipulate the transformation.

[image: Enter a value]

5. Click the Check mark in the Options Bar when you are happy with your transformations.